# Does GMAP.Net Have Google maps limitation in having 1500 query per day?

Tags: .net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, gmap.net

I want to use GMAP.NET component in my own software(written with C#.Net) for multiple users(maybe more than 500000) and use Google Maps. As you know Google map API have limitation of number of query in a day for a device. does GMAP.NET have this limitation? if so, this means that I must limit my users to use the map? having an premiere api needs to pay about 100$ each year for every users. isn't a free way to use google maps without this limitation?
how much query does a ordinary user nedds aday?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Maps through GMAP.Net, there are several things that need to be understood.

1. Google Maps might not be usable out of the predefined scenario as described in the terms of use, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms
2. Getting access to Google Maps out of their own controls is forbidden and, but I might be wrong, GMAP.Net control uses direct tile access (forbidden) or other service out of the control, see the paragraph below.
3. Since you're using the service and element, same licensing and limitation would occur.

Anyway, but I hope that someone would confirm, using GMAP.NET project is not something reliable while using Google Maps beneath in terms of licensing, terms of use and limitations.

> (a) No Access to Maps API(s) except through the Service. You must not
>   access or use the Maps API(s) or any Content through any technology or
>   means other than those provided in the Service, or through other
>   explicitly authorized means Google may designate. For example, you
>   must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels
>   (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).